# bootstrap tour for multipage. redirect but not strat next page tour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-tour

I am uisng [bootstraptour.com](http://bootstraptour.com)  for multipages tour.

I have separate demo.js which contain all code and included in all two page.

when i click on take a tour button it strat tour and when it redirect next.php it not show any more step.

when i am redirect to another page it stop to show next step.

it stop tour.

how can i fix this multipage tour.

**Code**

```
$(function(){

    var $demo, duration, remaining, tour;
    $demo = $("#taketour");
    storage:false,
    duration = 5000;
    remaining = duration;

tour = new Tour({
//      //storage : false,
//      onStart: function() {
//          ///return $demo.addClass("disabled", true);
//      },
//      onEnd: function() {
//          return $demo.removeClass("disabled", true);
//      },
    debug:true,     
    name: "tour"
}).init();

tour.addSteps([
    {
        //path:"home.php",
        element: "#a",
        placement: "right",
        title: "step1 ",
        content: "1"
    },
    {
        element: "#b",
        placement: "right",
        title: "s2",
        content: "c2"
    },
        {
        path:'next.php'
        element: "#na",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "na1",
        content: "na1"
    },
    {
        element: "#nat",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "na2",
        content: "na2"
    }
    ]);


$("#taketour").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("call tour");
    //      if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    //          return;
    //      }
    tour.restart();
    if (tour.ended()) {
        console.log("tour end");
        tour.restart();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tour starts only when the **'#taketour'** element is clicked. When you move on to the next page, the tour hasn't started yet. Hence you dont see it on screen as well.

You may well have to do something like this,

```
if(tour.started() && !tour.ended())
    {
        tour.init();
        tour.start();
    }
```

to check if the tour has not ended and hence start the tour from where you left off in the previous page. This obviously will work only if **you haven't set storage:false** when creating a new tour.

Comment: I have demo.js which contain all code and included in all two page.

Comment: which is Ok, but then does do you click the '#taketour' button in all two pages?

Comment: There is no method `.started()` but you nailed it with `.ended()` which wouldn't return true if the tour wasn't started in the first place. +1 from me